Count how many of each distinct combination exist across multiple columns
I am currently working with a dataset that corresponds the position of different vials within storage, for example looking like:
Product_number      Rack     Box    Slot
1                   1         2       5
1                   1         2       6
2                   3         5       18
3                   1         1       60
4                   4         6       48
4                   4         6       8
4                   4         7       15

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to use SQL to calculate the total number of each rack and box combination grouped by product number. So, for this example, I would want to display:
Product_number      Rack     Box    Number_of_vials
1                   1        2      2 
2                   3        5      1
3                   1        1      1
4                   4        6      2
4                   4        7      1

I know I can get a total count of the number of vials for each product number by using
select col1, count(col1) from sheet
group by col1

but I now need to break each of those product numbers down to show the rack/box combination and count.
I've looked a little bit at the count(distinct(concat)) function, but that seemed to be doing something else.
EDIT: problem solved by using multiple group by arguments. It turns out the real issue was a ton of null values hiding from me and making it look like the product number column had been nulled out.

Isn't it just a case of group by Product_number, Rack, Box?

Something like select col1, col2, col3, count(*) from sheet group by col1, col2, col3. The count(*) counts rows included in each group. Depending on your needs, the variants count(col4) or count(distinct col4) might be appropriate as they may produce different results, depending on whether col4 has any null values or duplicates.

It seems you want SELECT Product_number, Rack, Box, COUNT(DISTINCT slot) AS Number_of_vials FROM sheet GROUP BY Product_number, Rack, Box; The options COUNT(*) or COUNT(slot) appear to be incorrect because this would count same rows as different combinations which would very likely be wrong. See https://dbfiddle.uk/SSFfMs_z. But who knows, maybe is this even exactly what you are after. Anyway, you should have sufficient information now to solve your issue.

group by is not limited to just one column, include the other needed columns just like you did in the select clause e.g. group by Product_number, Rack, Box

Is it a rule that product 1 can only be on rack 1 (for example)? ie is the sample representative?

@DaleK, yes, it was, thank you. I had tried this earlier but though it didn't work because apparently there were a ton of null values hidden in my table that it brought to the top; as a result, I thought the product number was returning as null across the board. When I ran it again this morning, however, I saw all the other product numbers. Thanks again for the help, even though the answer ended up being pretty basic!

If you want to use count(*) or count(slot) in the query ,you can use having
in the query like below
SELECT Product_number, Rack, Box, count(*) AS Number_of_vials
FROM sheet
GROUP BY Product_number, Rack, Box
Having count(distinct slot)=count(*);

And this query will give the same result.
+----------------+------+------+-----------------+
| Product_number | Rack | Box  | Number_of_vials |
+----------------+------+------+-----------------+
|              1 |    1 |    2 |               2 |
|              2 |    3 |    5 |               1 |
|              3 |    1 |    1 |               1 |
|              4 |    4 |    6 |               2 |
|              4 |    4 |    7 |               1 |
+----------------+------+------+-----------------+


Why should they use a HAVING clause?

SELECT
    product_number,
    rack,
    box,
    COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    product_number,
    rack,
    box
ORDER BY
    product_number,
    rack,
    box;


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
